# Periodicity of SymPy trigonometric function

Tags: sympy

Sympy's trigonometric functions takes periodic argument into account.

```
from sympy import pi, sin, Symbol

n = Symbol('n', integer=True)

>>> sin(2*pi + 4)
sin(4)

>>> sin(n*pi)
0
```

However, it seems that it does not support this feature...

```
n = Symbol('n', integer=True)

>>> sin(2*n*pi + 4)
sin(2*n*pi + 4)  # Expected sin(4)
```

`.simplify()` or `.doit()` was not working. Is there any function or method to convert `sin(2*n*pi + 4)` to `sin(4)`?

Comment: note that this is now fixed and works as expected! (thanks to the users here and a GSoC contributor)! https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/17976 https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/19741

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `trigsimp` or seemingly clunky expansion and rewriting:

```
>>> eq = sin(2*n*pi + 4)
>>> eq.rewrite(exp).expand().rewrite(sin).expand()
sin(4)
>>> trigsimp(eq)
sin(4)
```

Comment: This should probably work without user intervention. It would be worth opening an issue at https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues .